# How to add Doxygen Comments for "C" variables with long type names

Tags: doxygen

I have a code

```
   static const guint8 variable;
```

when I put a documentation

```
/**
 * \var static const guint8 variable;
 * \brief This is a variable
 */
static const guint8 variable;
```

I do not get any output in the generated documentation. However, when the same thing is done with a simple variable decleration:

```
/**
 * \var int someothervar;
 * \brief This is some other variable
 */
int variable;
```

it does work

is that I am making some mistake in the usage ?

Thanks for any help in advance,

- elechi

Comment: This has to be a bug in Doxygen.

Answer (score 8):

For extracting static variables you should set EXTRACT_STATIC to YES.

If the documentation is in front of the variable, you do not need (and should not use) \var

Either set EXTRACT_ALL to YES or add a comment with a @file command in your code to document the file itself.